# Create chart from Multiple reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-xi

I'm new to Crystal Reports. I want to create a warehouse stock report on daily basis which i am able to do.

I have to show the date & weight of the stock in a graph and that is easy for each day.

Now the problem is i have to show all previous records also, e.g. if i take the report today and then i take report tomorrow then i have to show both the graphs in one report, and similarly for whole month.

Can anyone give me an idea how to create graph from values in different reports. Or is that even possible or not. Or any workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like subreports would address your use case (Insert, Subreport...).

Comment: I tried to use the subreport but then each subreport is creating its own graph/chart. Is it possible to create only one chart from the data coming from main & subreports?